# Making the span sticky in horizontal scroll without using Position:sticky

Tags: jquery, html, css, horizontal-scrolling

Making the span sticky in horizontal scroll without using Position:sticky

```css
ul.outer-ul {
    display: flex;
    min-width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 32px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
    background-color: rgba(156, 164, 182, 0);
}

li.inner-li {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
}

span.inner-header {
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-200px);
  transform-origin: left top 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: black;
  font-size:30px;
}
.inner-div {
    background-color: #fdfdfd;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 8px;
    color: rgba(45, 41, 38, 1);
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<ul class="outer-ul">

    <li class="inner-li">
        <span class="inner-header">A</span>
        <div class="inner-div">A1</div>
        <div class="inner-div">A2</div>
        <div class="inner-div">A3</div>

    </li>
    <li class="inner-li">
            <span class="inner-header">B</span>
            <div class="inner-div">B1</div>
            <div class="inner-div">B2</div>
    </li>
    <li class="inner-li">
            <span class="inner-header">C</span>
            <div class="inner-div">C1</div>
            <div class="inner-div">C2</div>
            <div class="inner-div">C3</div>
            <div class="inner-div">C4</div>
    </li>
    <li class="inner-li">
            <span class="inner-header">D</span>
            <div class="inner-div">D1</div>
            <div class="inner-div">D2</div>
            <div class="inner-div">D3</div>
    </li>
    <li class="inner-li">
            <span class="inner-header">E</span>
            <div class="inner-div">E1</div>
            <div class="inner-div">E2</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I did that using position sticky but its not working in IE. Is there any way to do this.
Its like when i scroll header should be like sticky.until its li is not over when the next li comes its span should be shown.
Is there any way in Jquery or CSS which we can do this.Fiddle link
https://jsfiddle.net/xrymt3a9/3

I want my code to work like the below example: https://codepen.io/geddski/pen/rjYpVr .But the issue in IE it doesnt work

Kindly Help?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Could you profide a jsfiddle of the problem?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xrymt3a9/3/

Comment: While horizontal scrolling the span should be fixed until li scroll is completed.For example li has span 'A' and three div 'A1','A2','A3' when i scroll until A3 it should show A has fixed in left side. next same for B and C header

Comment: So do you want to have your <span> that's inside "inner-li" to be fixed inside the element, so when the li scrolls out of vision, the <span> should be gone too?

Comment: I want my code to work like the below example: https://codepen.io/geddski/pen/rjYpVr .But the issue in IE it doesnt work

Comment: First of all, you should have posted the working code here in the question, rather than as an afterthought in a comment. Only after seeing the codepen can we tell what you're after! Anyway, there are many solutions available that make `sticky` work in IE. I don't know which one to recommend over the others, but you can do a search for **ie11 position sticky polyfill** and pick one yourself.

Comment: position sticky polyfill solution are also for certain cases only.doesn't support left, right, bottom or combined stickies.So is there any other solution.thanks for your time